# Unity: Instantiate Object at position of another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, multiplayer

I may be going about this the wrong way but I want to have the playerPrefab spawn at the object playerSpawn. Currently it spawns at some other location.

```
var made = Network.Instantiate(playerPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);

made.GetComponent(playerMove).playerName = playerName;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Object.Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-NetworkInstantiate.html)**
public static Object **Instantiate**(Object original, Vector3 **position**, Quaternion rotation);

You can specify the "spawn" position by using the second parameter, **position**.

Same is true for [Network.Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

Comment: Even if the object is in a different scene?

Comment: In that case just have a GameObject hold the spawn value and have it persist across scenes. [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) will achieve that for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't exactly understand. As I can't put the playerSpawn in the inspector from the other scene.

Comment: But you can get it in code by using `GameObject.Find("myGameObject").position;`

Comment: this got the player to spawn. But I got the error below.
var made = Network.Instantiate(playerPrefab, Vector3.position, transform.rotation, 0);
DontDestroyOnLoad(GameObject.Find("playerSpawn").position).playerName = playerName;

InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in Networking/$lobbySpawn$38/$:MoveNext (): IL_00af: castclass 0x01000042

Comment: Use `DontDestroyOnLoad(GameObject.Find("playerSpawn"));`. DontDestroyOnLoad needs to be applied to the GameObject directly.